# What is the proper way to do an HTTP GET on older versions of Android?

Tags: android, android-networking

I've been having an issue making HTTP GET requests consistent between versions of Android. On Android 7-12, this code works perfectly for accessing my remote server, and gets a response back relatively quickly.

```kotlin
            executor.execute { //send an HTTP GET Request to the server, send out some mail babyyyyy
                try {
                    val geturl = URL(url)
                    var jsonstring = geturl.readText();
                    var obj:JSONObject = JSONObject(jsonstring)
                    success = obj.getBoolean("success")
                    println(jsonstring)

                } catch(e:Exception) {
                    success=false;
                    println(e)

                }

                handler.post { //clean up, we're done here
```

However, when I try to run the exact same code under android 6.01, for example, I get returned a FileNotFoundException. How am I to make requests on versions lower than 7.0, and am I even doing this right? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). It works on Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and Java 8+ or [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: @talhatek edit: i'll implement that right now actually. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, massive thanks to @talhatek to pointing me in the right direction, but OkHTTP Worked great! complete set in replacement for the code I had previously, and my app's now working on android 6.0. For anyone needing the code, here's how I reimplemented it.

```kotlin
            executor.execute { //send an HTTP GET Request to the server, send out some mail babyyyyy
                try {
                    val client = OkHttpClient()
                    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build()

                    client.newCall(request).execute()
                        .use { response ->
                            //handle stuff
                        }

                } catch(e:Exception) {
                    success=false;
                    println(e)

                }
```